# Video compression before uploading to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-storage, expo, react-native-image-picker

I am a bit confused when it comes to the size of a video. I am currently using a `signedUrl` in order to send the video from the client phone to the Google Cloud Storage bucket. The part I am confused is in regards to the size of the video. I noticed when I upload a video that is a minute long, the size is over 200mb. Is this normal? or is there a way to decrease the video size since it seems like the cost would be exponential if that was the case.

When retrieving a video currently I have it as

```
let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
  videoQuality: 6
});
```

The videoQuality at 6 from my understanding produces `1280 x 720` resolution. Is the resolution an issue?

Thanks in advance for advice/help in hopefully solving this issue or teaching me what to consider when dealing with videos and uploading them to the cloud (in regards to space and storage).

Comment: Fighting with the same issue for a month, tried several ideas but any of them didn't work. please tell me when you get some idea.

Comment: @pankajchaturvedi you may find my answer useful

Answer (score 0):

The `videoQuality` argument should be of type `ImagePicker.UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-image-picker/src/ImagePicker.types.ts#LC35:%7E:text=export%20enum%20UIImagePickerControllerQualityType%20%7B,%7D)

The `ImagePicker.UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` currently has the following possible values as you can see in their [repo](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/master/packages/expo-image-picker/src/ImagePicker.types.ts#LC35:%7E:text=export%20enum%20UIImagePickerControllerQualityType%20%7B,%7D):

```
export enum UIImagePickerControllerQualityType {
  High = 0,
  Medium = 1,
  Low = 2,
  VGA640x480 = 3,
  IFrame1280x720 = 4,
  IFrame960x540 = 5,
}
```

Thus, for a `1280 x 720` output, you should set `videoQuality: 4`

Moreover, if you would like to further reduce the size of your video files when uploading to Google Cloud Storage, you may want to look into the [Decompressive transcoding feature](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/transcoding#decompressive_transcoding:%7E:text=If%20files%20are%20stored%20as%20gzip%2Dcompressed,before%20being%20sent%20to%20a%20requester), which automatically decompresses gzip files stored in GCS when they are requested (note that files should be compressed before storing in GCS).